# Setting a toolbar background color based on theme attribute crash the app

Tags: android, colors, reference, attributes, toolbar

So, i am setting a color of the toolbar by choosing the theme from settings...the color should be the color_primary.
When i set "?attr/color_primary" to the background of the toolbar the app crash 
with this error:
https://github.com/Heromine/tempapp1/issues/5
(i post the link because i get an error pasting here the error, sorry)

So here is the styles.xml with the themes:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


<!-- Activity themes -->

<style name="Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat" />




<!-- Application themes. -->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">?attr/color_primary</item>
</style>



<!-- Application themes. -->
<style name="AppTheme.Brown" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

    <item name="color_primary_dark">@color/minecraft_brown_dark_dirt_light</item>
    <item name="color_primary">@color/minecraft_brown_dirt_darkest</item>
    <item name="color_accent">@color/minecraft_green_grass_lightest</item>
    <item name="color_drawer_divider">?attr/color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">?attr/color_primary</item>
    <item name="color_preferences">@color/minecraft_brown_dirt_light</item>

    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">?attr/color_primary</item>

    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">?attr/color_primary_dark</item>

    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="colorAccent">?attr/color_accent</item>

</style>


<style name="AppTheme.Green" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

    <item name="color_primary_dark">@color/minecraft_green_cactus_darkest</item>
    <item name="color_primary">@color/minecraft_green_cactus_light</item>
    <item name="color_accent">@color/minecraft_brown_dirt_dark</item>
    <item name="color_drawer_divider">@color/minecraft_green_grass_lightest</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">?attr/color_primary</item>
    <item name="color_preferences">?attr/color_primary</item>

    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">?attr/color_primary</item>

    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">?attr/color_primary_dark</item>

    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="colorAccent">?attr/color_accent</item>

</style>


<style name="PreferenceFragmentTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/minecraft_brown_dirt_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/extracted_primary_text_default_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/extracted_secondary_text_default_material_light</item>
</style>


           <!-- LOOK HERE -->
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/color_primary</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ToolBarTheme</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ToolBarPopupTheme</item>
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/ToolBarTitleTheme</item>
    <item name="android:elevation" tools:targetApi="21">@dimen/elevation_default</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/toolbar_title_text_color</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolBarTitleTheme" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolBarPopupTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/minecraft_green_cactus_light</item>
</style>



<style name="CardViewStyle" parent="CardView.Light">
    <item name="cardUseCompatPadding">true</item>
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="cardElevation">4dp</item>
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">4dp</item>
</style>



<style name="ButtonTransparentStyle" parent="android:Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/extracted_secondary_text_default_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceButton</item>
</style>
```

attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<attr name="color_primary" format="color|reference" />
<attr name="color_primary_dark" format="color|reference" />
<attr name="color_accent" format="color|reference" />
<attr name="color_drawer_divider" format="color|reference" />
<attr name="color_preferences" format="color|reference" />
```

color.xml

```
<resources>

<color name="window_background">#CC000000</color>
<color name="greenactbar">#00ff11</color>
<item name="blue" type="color">#FF33B5E5</item>
<item name="purple" type="color">#FFAA66CC</item>
<item name="green" type="color">#FF99CC00</item>
<item name="orange" type="color">#FFFFBB33</item>
<item name="red" type="color">#FFFF4444</item>
<item name="darkblue" type="color">#FF0099CC</item>
<item name="darkpurple" type="color">#FF9933CC</item>
<item name="darkgreen" type="color">#FF669900</item>
<item name="darkorange" type="color">#FFFF8800</item>
<item name="darkred" type="color">#FFCC0000</item>
<item name="black" type="color">#FF000000</item>
<item name="white" type="color">#FFFFFFFF</item>

<item name="minecraft_button_background_not_pressed" type="color">#FF958681</item>
<item name="minecraft_button_background_pressed" type="color">#FF716567</item>
<item name="minecraft_button_text" type="color">#FFDEDEDE</item>
<item name="minecraft_button_text_shadow" type="color">#FF393939</item>
<item name="minecraft_button_light" type="color">#FFBCB1AB</item>
<item name="minecraft_button_dark" type="color">#FF282729</item>

<item name="minecraft_brown_dark_dirt_light" type="color">#FF3A2A1E</item>
<item name="minecraft_brown_dirt_darkest" type="color">#FF583D2B</item>
<item name="minecraft_brown_dirt_dark" type="color">#FF78543C</item>
<item name="minecraft_brown_dirt_light" type="color">#FF956B4D</item>
<item name="minecraft_brown_dirt_lightest" type="color">#FFB88460</item>

<item name="minecraft_green_grass_darkest" type="color">#FF406129</item>
<item name="minecraft_green_grass_dark" type="color">#FF476D2D</item>
<item name="minecraft_green_grass_light" type="color">#FF537D35</item>
<item name="minecraft_green_grass_lightest" type="color">#FF679940</item>

<item name="minecraft_green_cactus_darkest" type="color">#FF116120</item>
<item name="minecraft_green_cactus_light" type="color">#FF17832A</item>
<item name="minecraft_green_cactus_lightest" type="color">#FF199130</item>


<!-- colors of element of the app -->
<color name="toolbar_title_text_color">@color/white</color>
<color name="tabs_indicator_color">@color/white</color>
<color name="tabs_selected_text_color">@color/white</color>
<color name="tabs_not_selected_text_color">@color/minecraft_button_light</color>
<color name="drawer_text_shadow_color" type="color">#FF292929</color>
<color name="text_changelog_color" type="color">#FFA5A5A5</color>

<!-- colors used for the Settings page, on pre-lollipop devices the colors were different -->
<color name="extracted_primary_text_default_material_light">#de000000</color>
<color name="extracted_secondary_text_default_material_light">#8a000000</color>
<color name="material_deep_purple_500">@color/purple</color>
<color name="lannister">@color/purple</color>
<color name="textBackground">#8a000000</color>



<integer-array name="androidcolors">
    <item>@color/blue</item>
    <item>@color/purple</item>
    <item>@color/green</item>
    <item>@color/orange</item>
    <item>@color/red</item>
    <item>@color/darkblue</item>
    <item>@color/darkpurple</item>
    <item>@color/darkgreen</item>
    <item>@color/darkorange</item>
    <item>@color/darkred</item>
    <item>@color/black</item>
    <item>@color/white</item>
</integer-array>



</resources>
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>

<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I am on Android 5.0.2,  no need answer for version before lollipop

Comment: You can't reference style attributes in the colors resources file, at least not before lollipop. You can only reference style attributes in styles and in layouts.

Comment: I am in lollipop and the app is for Android 5+

Comment: After checking: on Lollipop you can do it inside drawable resources but not in color resources, so my remark stays valid.

Comment: but it is what i am doing, i am referencing of the color_primary that is different if i choose the green or the brown theme, look at the styes.xml

Comment: In color.xml you can *not* reference a style attribute, only plain colors. It must be the other way around: in the style attribute you reference the color. I don't know how to explain it better.

Comment: i understand, it is what i am doing, color.xml has no reference also no reference to the styles.xml, by the way styles.xml has reference to color.xml

Comment: I've seen you have edited the code of colors.xml in your question and now it looks correct.

Comment: yes because i thought it was confusing you. i didn't use that it was only an old test, currently i don't use it and it seems it doesn't work yet.

Comment: Do you still have the exact same crash? The stack trace you posted indicates that the background drawable of the Toolbar can not be resolved.

Comment: same crash everytime, i also tried to change other thing to see if it is a toolbar bug but it is not, it is an attribute bug

Comment: Maybe try to change your custom attributes definitions to `format="color"` (with no reference). Or remove the duplicate ones (color_primary seems to do the same as AppCompat's colorPrimary)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the background of toolbar to the color you want like this:

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/your_primary_color"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
```

Or you can change that programmatically by the setBackground() method...no need to use attrs here...but if you need to use attrs then appcompat makes it possible to use on older android versions just by removing the "android:" prefix like this : "?attr/your_attr"

Comment: Do you use appcompat?

Comment: Anyway you could try setting the background to the color using @color/

Comment: i am using Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar as you can see, since i use themes if i set a normal @color/... it won't change by changing theme, so i should use ?attr/...

Comment: It's perfectly valid to use a style attribute to reference the background color in the layout, but it's not valid to use a style attribute as a definition of a color in `color.xml`. Color resources must contain invariable colors that you can then select in your theme then reference as style attributes in your layouts.

Comment: It is what I am trying to do, check the xml (don't look at the first 4 lines, they aren't used)